Must the non-Muktzeh item be more valuable than the total Muktzeh, or each individual Muktzeh item?
The rule is, that in order for one to be allowed to move an item that contained something that was Muktzeh when Shabbat came in, it must have also contained an item that was not Muktzeh, and that item must be more valuable than the Muktze-item (OC 310:8)
My question is: if there there were multiple Muktzeh-items, then does the non-muktheh-item need to be more valuable than all of the Muktzeh-items put together, or is it enough for it to be more valuable than each one individually?
